# Trying to identify a filesystem / disk label, recover it

Tags: filesystems, recovery, data-recovery

I'm trying to ID (and maybe recover) the filesystem/partition table. Friend brought a "broken" USB drive, Windows can't recognise the partition layout.

Under Linux, `fdisk` says the partition table is empty. Tried mounting it as NTFS, vfat, no luck. With `fdisk`/`mkfs`, created an empty: DOS partition table, ntfs and fat filesystems, tried to compare magic numbers in the first block of the respective three and the broken drive - none seem alike. `dd`'d the first 1MB of the drive to a file on disk (so that `file` doesn't say it's a block device), `file` said "data".

This is the first 8 lines of `hd`:

```
00000000  0e 21 e9 6e 2c 64 39 b5  63 bf a5 08 8b 07 85 a6  |.!.n,d9.c.......|
00000010  63 aa ec 58 c3 ff fb 92  64 ec 80 02 f4 3c 4c d1  |c..X....d....<L.|
00000020  8f 2a e4 58 24 39 ba 3d  86 4a 8e e0 d3 27 ac 60  |.*.X$9.=.J...'.`|
00000030  eb 81 73 9f 26 68 f6 15  72 60 02 6b 32 32 4c 75  |..s.&h..r`.k22Lu|
00000040  b1 0a cd ff ff ff f4 ea  23 c8 2a ba 25 01 20 9d  |........#.*.%. .|
00000050  26 52 b1 31 2c 4d 72 b1  2f bc 9f 1f 59 5b 98 98  |&R.1,Mr./...Y[..|
00000060  41 9d 3c 10 17 d0 58 9a  ab 24 d9 31 ff 3a 79 55  |A.<...X..$.1.:yU|
00000070  f3 88 08 6b 57 ec 7a 5f  ff e0 21 c7 87 4c 62 83  |...kW.z_..!..Lb.|
```

Any idea how to proceed with the recovery?

Answer (score 0):

If you study fdisk code on Linux, you will see code to create/parse a Master Boot Table. This is the table that contains diff codes for diff boot partitions, starting block/offset, bootable/non-bootable flag, etc. If this table is corrupted, then it is difficult to recover.

One option is to find out where the MBT is stored on USB...usually, it is a standard location based on the file system. If the data there is not readable, then go beyond it and see where the first file system block is resident (most probably also a fix starting location. If the hex dump is recognizable at this location, create a MBT with this block number and see if the boot works..

The other option is to find out if there is a duplicate copy of MBT stored by the FS on the USB. Study the File system that formatted the USB and you may get closer.